# guternbery editor: javascripte modified content to save to block object

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

i am writing a plugin for wordpress, and in this plugin, i modified the html content in the editor, after the modification, i want to save the content, but after hitting the publish button, the post  remains unmodified.  i tried to use the wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').updatePost, and similar api, but the content is still unmodified.

here is the javascript:

```
(function($){
     $('.frc_remove_origin').on('click', function(){

          if(!confirm("origin text will be removed ")){
            return;
        }
           $('.frc_trim_origin_btn').remove();

            wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').savePost();
          return;
      })

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell, function using `wp.data.dispatch()` need to be wrapped in `wp.data.withDispatch()` to actually work. This is the [post](https://riad.blog/2018/06/07/efficient-client-data-management-for-wordpress-plugins/) I followed to get mine working.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it would have been better to write the answer directly here on SO. External links can become invalid ;-)